# How to make modification Android Snackbar containing with LayoutInflater button and editText

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, snackbar

My project now is how to make a Snackbar displayed at the bottom of the screen. The Snackbar contain with editText and three button for selection categories. 
I use LayoutInflater and follow these [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42003260/how-to-add-edittext-in-snackbar-in-android-programmatically) for my script, and it's work. My problem now is, how to get response when user click the button ? 
Here my code

```
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {

            CoordinatorLayout linearLayout = (CoordinatorLayout)findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);

            final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(linearLayout, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
            Snackbar.SnackbarLayout layout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();

            // Inflate your custom view with an Edit Text
            LayoutInflater objLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View snackView = objLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_snac_layout, null);
            // custom_snac_layout is your custom xml

            layout.addView(snackView, 0);
            snackbar.show();

        }
```

and here my snacbar.xml layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<EditText
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/event_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:hint="@string/type_your_message"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
    android:maxLines="4"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btn_mapel"
    android:onClick="mapel"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin_bottom"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_image_edit" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin_bottom"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_image_edit" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin_bottom"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_image_edit" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is the source required to implement button listener to your snackbar custom layout.

```
@Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

        CoordinatorLayout linearLayout = (CoordinatorLayout)findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);

        final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(linearLayout, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        Snackbar.SnackbarLayout layout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();

        // Inflate your custom view with an Edit Text
        LayoutInflater objLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View snackView = objLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_snac_layout, null);
        // custom_snac_layout is your custom xml

        // button id for snackbar
        Button button_mapel = (Button) snackView.findViewById(R.id.btn_mapel);

        // perform button click listener
        button_mapel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           // here perform your button click task
           }
        });

        layout.addView(snackView, 0);
        snackbar.show();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. It's resolve my problem, less than one hour.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this documentation

> https://developer.android.com/training/snackbar/action.html

```
public class MyUndoListener implements View.OnClickListener{

    &Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Code to undo the user's last action
    }
}
```

Now for setAction()

```
Snackbar mySnackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.myCoordinatorLayout),
                                R.string.email_archived, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
mySnackbar.setAction(R.string.undo_string, new MyUndoListener());
mySnackbar.show();
```

Comment: I can't find editText included with these example, that's why i use LayoutInflater. Have another idea?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get id of your `Button`. And have to set `clickListener`.

You have to just replace your code with this.

I have put listener on `btn_mapel`, you can put any other button according to your requirement.

**Try this.**

```
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

        CoordinatorLayout linearLayout = (CoordinatorLayout)findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);

        final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(linearLayout, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        Snackbar.SnackbarLayout layout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();

        // Inflate your custom view with an Edit Text
        LayoutInflater objLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View snackView = objLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_snac_layout, null);
        // custom_snac_layout is your custom xml

        Button mapelBt = (Button)snackView.findViewById(R.id.btn_mapel);

        mapelBt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             // Get your button click callback here
        }
    });


        layout.addView(snackView, 0);
        snackbar.show();

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This,

```
Button btn_feed_back = (Button)snackView.findViewById(R.id.feedback);
    btn_feed_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```